# How do I invert a grayscale image and convert it to a binary image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to create an image like this:
[image]
From an image like this:
[alt text http://internationalpropertiesregistry.com/Server/showFile.php?file=%2FUpload%2Funtitled.jpgb523c7595dd8e7514e1c6d51a83161a3.jpeg](http://internationalpropertiesregistry.com/Server/showFile.php?file=%2FUpload%2Funtitled.jpgb523c7595dd8e7514e1c6d51a83161a3.jpeg)

**UPDATE**

Here's what's generated by `255-img`, but the result doesn't match exactly:
[alt text http://internationalpropertiesregistry.com/Server/showFile.php?file=%2FUpload%2Funtitled.jpg61f9edbeb4f0285c2a1772cced3ce393.jpeg](http://internationalpropertiesregistry.com/Server/showFile.php?file=%2FUpload%2Funtitled.jpg61f9edbeb4f0285c2a1772cced3ce393.jpeg)

Comment: i don't know about matlab, but it would sure be easier to do if you could reverse the white square in the first image instead of leaving just it the same color.  Perhaps all you need to do is adjust the plot settings before you draw it?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what type your input matrix is.

If it is a logical matrix you can simply use

```
invImg = ~img;
```

If you have scalar values in the range of 0 to n use

```
invImg = n - img;
```

**Edit:**

If you want a black and white image try the following (perhaps you need to play with the *level* paramter):

```
invImg = ~im2bw(img, 0.5);
```

Comment: The grids are still there. They're just very weak.

Comment: It's because the gridlines aren't black in the white background image, they're gray.

Answer (score 3):

I had some trouble processing the second image you posted above. Since it's in JPEG format, the image compression seems to have made the lines and text fuzzy, and that complicates thresholding it in the way that you want.

I instead went back to the indexed-color GIF image you posted on [the previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973973/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-with-matlab-unit-mh), converted it to grayscale (using the function [IND2GRAY](http://www.mathworks.cn/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/ind2gray.html) from the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.cn/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/)), then converted that to a reversed black and white image to match the format of the first image you posted above. Here's the code I used:

```
[X,map] = imread('original_chart.gif');  %# Load the indexed color image
img = ind2gray(X,map);                   %# Convert the image to grayscale
reversedImage = img < max(img(:));       %# Convert to reversed black and white
```

And here's what `reversedImage` looks like:

[image]

Comment: can you take a look how's the graph generated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973973/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-with-matlab-unit-mh/2975223#2975223

Answer (score 3):

How about just flipping the colormap?

colormap(flipud(colormap));

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the 3rd plot is the reverse of the 2nd above.

One thing to consider is what you are using for draw image `image()` `imagesc()` or `imshow()`
`imagesc()` does auto scaling and `imshow()` will use a color map.

Another thing to consider is the input image itself.  Does it range from 0 - 255, 0 - 1.0 or RGB?  Depending on what it is, the reverse would be different.

Answer (score 1):

Your images aren't binary black & white.  There's gray in there as well.

Given from your edit that you seem to what any on pixel to be off, and any off pixel to be on (ie, convert it to a straight binary black and white image), this should do what you want:

```
newImg = zeros(size(img));
newImg(img > 0) = 0;    % <-- This line is not really needed
newImg(img = 0) = 1;
```

Note that the 2nd line isn't strictly necessary since the new image is being initialized to 0 anyways, it's just in to show what exactly is going on.