# Inversion of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

How do you invert an image (reversing grayscale) in MATLAB?

Comment: this appears to be a duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980860/how-do-i-reverse-the-color-of-a-grayscale-image-in-matlab

Comment: @Marc: The title of the other question is probably a little misleading. In that question, the OP actually seems to want a *binary* image as an output, not a reversed *grayscale* image. I'll try to edit it to be clearer.

Answer (score 9):

If it's a [grayscale intensity image](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-175) of class `uint8`, you can do this:

```
reversedImg = 255-img;
```

If it's a [grayscale intensity image](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-175) of class `double`, the pixel values should be between 0 and 1, so you can do this:

```
reversedImg = 1-img;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you're looking for the [imcomplement function](http://www.mathworks.it/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imcomplement.html) if you have the imaging processing toolbox.

Answer (score -2):

use img=~img.

it may work I guess.

Comment: This reverses a binary image, not a grayscale image. Also, avoid answering questions that are over 4 years old, especially when there is an accepted or highly voted  answer.