# How can I invert a binary image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary

I have a binary image and need to convert all of the black pixels to white pixels and vice versa. Then I need to save the new image to a file. Is there a way to do this without simply looping over every pixel and flipping its value?

Comment: It would depend on [what sort of image you're dealing with](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html) (RGB, indexed, grayscale, binary), but the answer is probably already covered here: [How do I invert a grayscale image and convert it to a binary image in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980860/how-do-i-invert-a-grayscale-image-and-convert-it-to-a-binary-image-in-matlab)

Comment: @gnovice i'm dealing with binary image. I thought to move on all the pixels in the image and just change 0 to 1 and vice versa, but i'm not Matlab expert and i'm not sure how to do it. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a binary image `binImage` with just zeroes and ones, there are a number of simple ways to invert it:

```
binImage = ~binImage;
binImage = 1-binImage;
binImage = (binImage == 0);
```

Then just save the inverted image using the function [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `imcomplement` matlab function. Say you have a binary image b then,

```
bc = imcomplement(b); % gives you the inverted version of b
b = imcomplement(bc); % returns it to the original b
imwrite(bc,'c:\...'); % to save the file in disk
```

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, by using `not` we can convert *1's into 0's and 0's into 1's*.

```
inverted_binary_image = not(binary_image)
```

Comment: The `not` function is exactly what's called when using the `~` operator.

Answer (score -2):

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.bmp'},'Text as image');

img=imread(filename);
img=im2double(img);
[r,c,ch]=size(img);
%imshow(img);
invert_img=img;
if(ch==1)
 for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        if(invert_img(i,j)==0)
          invert_img(i,j)=1;
        else
          invert_img(i,j)=0;
        end
    end 
end
end
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution compared to those presented earlier, and does not even consider the requested saving of the image.