# Filtering out pixels in the green channel with MATLAB, etc

Tags: matlab, image-processing

It's from Stack Overflow question *[How do I calculate the area under a curve in an image with MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973973)*, but I'm also interested in this.

1. How do I filter out pixels not in the green channel?
2. And how do I select a point which is inside a closed box with **MATLAB**?

[Alt text http://internationalpropertiesregistry.com/Server/showFile.php?file=%2FUpload%2Fstatistics.gifc49ca28823a561a41d09ef9adbb5e0c5.gif](http://internationalpropertiesregistry.com/Server/showFile.php?file=%2FUpload%2Fstatistics.gifc49ca28823a561a41d09ef9adbb5e0c5.gif)

Comment: The image link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

For your two questions:

1. Colored pixels have red, green, and blue color components. Selecting pixels based on their color involves selecting how much of each RGB component is present in the pixel. For example, a pure white pixel has each color component at its maximum (1 if the image type is double precision, 255 if the image type is uint8). You can look at [my solution to the referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973973/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-with-matlab-unit-mh/2991410#2991410) to see one way you can select pixels based on their RGB components. You can also check out [this MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html) for more information about images and their data types.
2. One way to select a point is to let the user select it using the [GINPUT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ginput.html) function. For example, the following will let the user select 1 point from the current axes, returning the x and y coordinates where they click:

   ```
   [x,y] = ginput(1);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994675/image-processing-with-matlab/2994715#2994715)'s answer should suffice.

For the second question: Use a Monte Carlo approach: have the algorithm choose a random pixel using [RANDI](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html) (you may want to search within, say, 20 pixels of the center of the image to avoid problems with the border). If it's a green pixel, you try again. If it's a white pixel, you are inside one of the squares.