# Is there a tool to translate matlab to PHP automatically?

Tags: php, matlab, code-translation

Especially I want to translate [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973973/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-with-matlab-unit-mh/2991410#2991410) in matlab to PHP, is it viable?

Comment: Without much thinking about it: Try to find a programming language "between" matlab and PHP (such *could* be: Python, Ruby, Perl) and try to convert it "step by step". 

But I think it would be better to do it just by hand.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** This tool not exists.

But you can do this simple by hand using some `for` statements. With using GD and some code to Image Processing.

More information how to implement Image Processing you can find at http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: I never know `for` statement is so powerful ,can you elaborate?

Comment: @user198729: Some matlab function used in your linked code you can replace alternative by the simple for. In PHP language this functions not exists but PHP language is not for mathematican equations then you must write it by hand.