# Matlab fit graph to bw image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to convert images to graphs in Matlab. 

 The process is as follwing:

1. Taking an RGB image
2. Finding the axes and create the appropriate pixel-to-(x, y)-coordinates in graph
3. Convert the image to BW with some customizable `im2bw` , and
4. [That's the tricky part] Trying to come out with a line matching for the white pixels in the image.

I've been trying some snake and some grow-as-you-go algorithms to detect the graph from the white pixels in the BW image, but it seems weird that I can find no ready made Matlab algorithm which match all the white pixels in the BW image to an equation. Any help or ideas will be much appreciated.

[Edit] Here's an example for the BW image from the graph extracted:
[image]

Comment: If you're only doing one or two graphs and don't mind being clicky clicky click, then grabit from the file exchange is very useful. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7173-grabit Any more than that then an automated way is better, I'd be interested too see one too.

Comment: @Alex - Didn't know it's already in FileExchange, I programmed this part myself, with auto detection of axis by sum of rows and columns.

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I calculate the area under a curve in an image with MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973973/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-under-a-curve-in-an-image-with-matlab) It's not totally clear what you want to do, but I think you could look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973973/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-under-a-curve-in-an-image-with-matlab/2991410#2991410) to see how I extracted pixels for the axes, grid, and plot lines in that example. Once you get your pixel values for the graph, you can do curve-fitting.

Comment: I don't have the time for a complete answer, but here's a potential approach, in case you only have one line, or the lines are of different color. For each line: (1) use `find` to get the x,y values of the line, (2) if necessary, transform the coordinates using the axes, (3) use a smoothing spline (`csaps`, or `smoothn` from the FEX) to create a line that closely follows the points.

Comment: A nice little tool for manually picking points for graphs is [g3data](http://www.frantz.fi/software/g3data.php).

Comment: Nice tool @jarmond, but it's just for manual set of data points. As I said, it should be some automatic algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be done with MATLAB?

There is a list with [Digitizing programs for Converting Hard Copy Graphs and Plots back to Data](http://www.ccp14.ac.uk/solution/hardcopy2data.htm) on the CCP14 homepage; maybe you can use one of the tools found there? I haven't tried myself, but remember having come across the same issue...